# October cms image

Tags: image, octobercms

I am knew to October, does anyone know if it is possible to replace an icon with an image?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="services">
        <div class="service-item">
            <i class="icon-laptop"></i>
            <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>Random</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't relate specifically to October, that's just an HTML change.

Just replace the `<i class="icon-laptop"></i>` with `<img src="/path/to/your/image/here.png" alt="">`

Alternatively, if you want to use an image within your theme, you could do something like this: `<img src="{{ 'assets/images/laptop.png' | theme }}" alt="">`